# How to use org.eclipse.core.runtime.QualifiedName.QualifiedName(String qualifier, String localName) in eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In `QualifiedName` constructor what is the significance of first argument?

I saw there are instances in eclipse code where they are passing qualifer as `""` or `empty string`. What is the correct value for qualifier?

Comment: Normally it is a namespace id (often a plugin id). Where did you see a blank value?

Answer (score 1):

As @greg-449 already said, its a namespace to prevent naming conflicts with other plugins. I think a good practice is to use the plugin id or the full package name (in most cases this is the same)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The question was what is the significance of the argument qualifier, the answer is to prevent naming conflicts and sort a little. Where is that not an answer? I only got one thing wrong, it should be an URI not only the package name.

see: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FQualifiedName.html